# Can I use Corona sdk to execute git command?

Tags: git, coronasdk

I want use [corona sdk](http://docs.coronalabs.com/) to run some `git` command, like clone, or rebase.

Can I use corona to do it?
if yes, please give me some example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any integration with git in the [SDK API itself](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/), so the only way would be to use a [`os.execute()`](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/os/execute.html) function.

> Passes a string to the operating system for execution and returns a system-dependent status code. This function is equivalent to the C function `system()`.

Note that this function is only available in the Corona simulator. It does not work on the device, so it could not be what you are looking for.

Except for that function (simulator only), I didn't see a way to execute git command in the device with Corona SDK.

Comment: Thank you VonC, but this function only work in simulator, can you give me some suggestion about how to imply in the device?

Comment: @user2023809 in that case (device), I didn't see a way with Corona SDK. I have edited my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Note to self: user2023809's comment yesterday was my 10000th answer!